# How to convert a Constant* to Value* in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

I just want to obfuscate selector name, but I don't know How to convert a Constant* to Value* :

```
void symObfs(Module &M) {
            errs()<<"Start Obfuscating...\n";
            srand (time(NULL));
            //Objective-C Method ClassName Stuff
            for(auto G=M.getGlobalList().begin();G!=M.getGlobalList().end();G++){
                GlobalVariable &GL=*G;
                if (GL.getName().str().find("OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_")==0||GL.getName().str().find("OBJC_CLASS_NAME_")==0){
                    ConstantDataArray* Initializer=dyn_cast<ConstantDataArray>(GL.getInitializer ());
                    // string newName = fakeNameGenerator();
                    string newName = randomString(16);
                    Constant *Value =ConstantDataArray::getString(Initializer->getContext(),newName,true);
                    //GL.setInitializer(Value);
                    errs()<<"Selector Name: "<<Initializer->getAsCString ()<<" Obfuscated to: "<<newName<<"\n";
                    Initializer->Value::replaceAllUsesWith(Value);
                }
            }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [Constant](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Constant.html) Class inherits from the [Value](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html) Class.

So you do not need to do anything to convert from `Constant*` to `Value*`. You can directly assign a `Constant*` to a `Value*` since in C++ pointers to children class objects can be assigned to parent class pointers variables.

On the other hand if you want to assign from `Value*` to `Constant*` you will have to use `dyn_cast` as

```
Constant * C = dyn_cast<Constant*>(V);
```

This will set C to `NULL` if the object in V is not indeed a Constant.

Comment: but when I directly pass the value, when Xcode compiling the test project outputs: 
Start Obfuscating...
Selector Name: alloc Obfuscated to: 8e6yx4sg2hsihyr
Assertion failed: (New->getType() == getType() && "replaceAllUses of value with new value of different type!"), function replaceAllUsesWith, file /Users/renqiming/Desktop/llvm_3.9_mod/llvm-3.9.1.src/lib/IR/Value.cpp, line 380.

Comment: The issue is not with converting from Constant* to Value*, it is that the new constant you are creating (with obfuscated name) doesn't have the same type as your original constant. Trying dumping both the types and check if they are same.